# How to remove overlay image from Fabric.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I use overlay image on my Fabric.js and it is added like this:

```
canvas.setOverlayImage('image.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

My problem is that I can't find to method to remove it from canvas. To remove objects I can use `remove(object)` from class `fabric.StaticCanvas`, but I haven't found a way how to serve overlay image as object to this method. I have tries to set overlay image to `null`:

```
canvas.setOverlayImage(null, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it almost looks like a bug that you can't set it to null in the way you'd expect (as a parameter to setOverlayImage). Looking at [static_canvas.class.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/static_canvas.class.js) you see the source code for `setOverlayImage()`:

```
setOverlayImage: function (url, callback) { // TODO (kangax): test callback
  return fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(img) {
    this.overlayImage = img;
    callback && callback();
  }, this);
}
```

And in [util/misc.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/util/misc.js) you see the source code for `util.loadImage()`:

```
function loadImage(url, callback, context) {
  if (url) {
    var img = new Image();
    /** @ignore */
    img.onload = function () { 
      callback && callback.call(context, img);
      img = img.onload = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
  }
}
```

So you can see if you pass null to `setOverlayImage()`, null will in turn be the argument to `util.loadImage()`. And if the argument to the latter is null, the method does nothing, so in turn the whole operation does nothing.

It looks like you have to cheat and directly set the property on the `canvas` object:

```
canvas.overlayImage = null;
canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer! I should have looked into source also before posting here := I already made myself a work-around by setting and empty transparent PNG as overlay, but Your answer gives the correct way to do it.

Comment: Yep, that's an oversight on my part. Thanks for catching it. Just fixed it — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/0bb80dddf002292fb27017ba763f550d8b39bd8c

Answer (score 0):

I created a toggle that alternates between having an overlay image and a null overlay. This is possible after Kangax's update to the code:

```
function toggleOverlay(){
    if(!canvas.overlayImage){
        canvas.setOverlayImage(
            'img/transparent-overlay.png', 
            canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
        );
    }else{
        canvas.setOverlayImage(null, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Null just make it blank.

```
canvas.setOverlayImage('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Comment: Not working at my end. Switched to `setOverlayImage(null, ...` then it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same issue 
I fixed by setting  backgroundImage = 0

```
self.canvas.backgroundImage = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I could think of is setting the opacity to 0

```
canvas.overlayImage.set('opatcity', 0)
canvas.renderAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution i found.
`canvas.overlayImage?.dispose()` I found was used in the source code.

```
canvas.overlayImage?.dispose();
canvas.setOverlayImage('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```